# Running an applet in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, applet

I did a voice recorder applet and deployed in Apache Tomcat server.

In Windows I tested the URL (http://localhost/Sound.html) in Firefox and IE; it's working fine.

But the same applet is not loaded in Safari browser in Linux.

I have signed the applet too. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, does your Linux browser have Java support? Have you tried it on an applet you know does work?

Comment: Safari on Linux? Do you mean Firefox?

Comment: sorry safari in Mac os X

Comment: So, are you now asking why it doesn't work on Firefox / Linux, or why it is not working on Safari / Mac OS X? Please don't make this confusing!

Comment: The applet is working on firefox/windows and IE/windows !!!

Its not working on safari/mac os X and firefox/linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What version of what Linux distribution are you using?
- What version of what browser are you using on Linux? Does that browser support Java?
- Do you have Java installed on Linux?
- Do you have a Java browser plug-in installed on Linux?

If you are using Ubuntu and Firefox, then install Sun Java 6 by installing the package `sun-java6-plugin` using Synaptic or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-plugin
```